# Deleting World Data Block from the Outliner Tree

Tags: cycles-render-engine, outliner, data-blocks

Rookie errors! It seems at some point I have deleted the World Data block from the Outliner Tree. When I needed to create a World background I added a new World from the properties panel,[image] however the use Nodes button under the surface tab is no longer there. Is there any way that I can reinstate a World as it would be when opening a new file?
When I open Node Editor and go to Add Nodes the options are not available for selection. I changed the color to green in the properties window and see no Nodes. I presume I am missing a step.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any errror / unexpected behaviour on the second screenshot; Use Nodes button was pressed there and now it uses Background shader with unconnected Color and Strength input sockets. Open Node editor and you'll see nodes in more convenient way

Comment: @Mr Zak I have edited my question, added detail for further clarification.

Comment: @Mr Zak I have answered part of my question but when I went back to the file I was actually working on, I still have a problem. I will attach the .blend file perhaps that might help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the World nodes, all you have to do is switch from editing object material nodes to the world material nodes. To do so, click on the little world icon that can be found at the bottom of the node editor. It's the one located to the right of the cube icon that is currently selected (visible in the third screenshot). This will now display the world nodes.

[image]

Comment: It took me ages to figure that one out, when I first encountered this problem!

Comment: @Mr Zak Thank you. That seems to do the trick. Seems quite simple but as a beginner it can be quite tricky to know what is going wrong and how best to phrase a question!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the "missing" Nodes. Tick the use nodes box on the toolbar under the Nodes Editor.[image]